# "Unknown columns" error when executing a mass action

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, massaction

I built up a grid with mass action similiar to this examples:

[AbstractMassAction.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/AbstractMassAction.php)

[Mass Cancel](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/MassCancel.php)

When executing the code (see below) I get the following error message:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `my_custom_table` AS `main_table` WHERE (`IN('47', '48', '49')) AND (` IN('49'))

It seems that the code cannot identify the table columns when using the filter. Does anyone know what is the reason for this?

My Mass Action:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Vendor\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\MyModel\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;


/**
 * Class ExportXML
 */
class ExportXml extends AbstractMassAction {


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;

    /**
     * @var OrderFactory $orderFactory
     */
    private $orderFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param Filter $filter
     */
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, 
            CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
            Filter $filter) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $filter);
    }

    /**
     * Export rates grid to XML format
     *
     * @return ResponseInterface
     */
    protected function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection) {
        ...
```

My Abstract Mass Action

```
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\DebitReportModel\CollectionFactory;



abstract class AbstractMassAction extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {
    /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Micobo_DebitPayment::manage';
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectUrl = '*/*/index';
    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;
    /**
     * @var object
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, Filter $filter)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->filter = $filter;
//        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }
    /**
     * Execute action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException|\Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
            return $this->massAction($collection);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath($this->redirectUrl);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Return component referer url
     * TODO: Technical dept referer url should be implement as a part of Action configuration in in appropriate way
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    protected function getComponentRefererUrl()
    {
        return $this->filter->getComponentRefererUrl()?: 'customer/*/index';
    }
    /**
     * Execute action to collection items
     *
     * @param AbstractCollection $collection
     * @return ResponseInterface|ResultInterface
     */
    abstract protected function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection);
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It creates an issue because you didn't define `$_idFieldName` in your `ResourceModel` `Collection`

Please add this line in `Vendor\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\MyModel\Collection`file.

```
     /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY';
```

Where `$_idFieldName` is your table `primary key`.

Comment: Thank you! I did not find any hint that this field is required... Now it is working fine :-)

Comment: Glad to hear the it works for you. @Tenobi

Comment: @KeyurShah Thanks man you save my day while solving some one else's error

Comment: Glad that it helps you buddy :) @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: It's working for me!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem appeared because I put parent class invocation before the methods defining. And even though I had

```
protected $_idFieldName = 'YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY';
```

that didn't work me.